# How To Get Random Elements To Join Together

Tags: python, string, random

```
elements = ['why','where','what','who','when','how']
for x in range(5):
    length=(random.randint(1,5))
    whatever=""
    for y in range(1,length):
         whatever += elements[random.randint(0,5)]
         print whatever
```

I'm trying to get the above code to print and combine the elements from the list into random strings that consist of 1 to 4 syllables. Right now its printing a syllable at a time and then joining them together. After the string reaches 4 syllables, it restarts and does the process again.

This is what it prints:

```
why
whywhen
whywhenwhere
how
howwhy
howwhywhy
what
whatwhen
whatwhenhow
whatwhenhowwhen
```

Comment: I don't get that output at all when I run your code

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
elements = ['why','where','what','who','when','how']
for x in range(5):
    length=random.randint(1,5)
    whatever=""
    for y in range(length):
        whatever += elements[random.randint(0,5)]
    print whatever
```

Range does not include the last element, so `for y in range(1, length)` will give you length-1 iterations, whereas `range(length)` will give you 0 through length-1 for a total of `length` iterations.

And your print statement needs to be outside the loop so you only print at the end when `whatever` is fully built up to `length` syllables.